# Detect LineString Geojson is String

Tags: javascript, geojson, turfjs

how to detect linestring forming a ring ? Like the following picture:
I've been looking for it with turfjs, but haven't found the right one:
[image]

````js
 const paths = [
        [121.533155, 25.054599],
        [121.533207, 25.057867],
        [121.533207, 25.057867],
        [121.536712, 25.057837],
        [121.536618, 25.054634],
        [121.536585, 25.053594],
        [121.534815, 25.053634],
        [121.534819, 25.054786],
        [121.532407, 25.054832],
      ];

      const lineString = turf.lineString(paths);
      const routeArea: Feature<Polygon> = turf.buffer(lineString, 50, {
        units: 'meters',
      });
      if (routeArea.geometry.coordinates.length > 1) {
        const coord = routeArea.geometry.coordinates;
        const cloneRouteArea: Feature<Polygon> = {
          ...routeArea,
          properties: {
            pathColor: getAreaOutlineColor(pathColor),
            outlineColor: getAreaOutlineColor(pathColor),
          },
          geometry: {
            ...routeArea.geometry,
            coordinates: coord,
          },
        };
    ```
````